# multi-Insert using sqlsrv_query

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-insert, sqlsrv

the code below is designed to insert n rows into a table. However, for all n >=108, it manages to insert only 108 rows. Works fine for n<108.  I run the query on database and it works as expected. Has any of you guys had a similar issue?. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    $data = "a1='1', a2='2', a3='3', a4='4', a5='5', a6='6'";
    $queryInsert = 
    "   SELECT $data INTO [$tableName]
        DECLARE @i int
        SET @i=1
        WHILE (@i < $n)
        BEGIN
            INSERT [$tableName]
            SELECT $data
            SET @i = @i + 1
        END
    ";
    $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($conn1, $queryInsert);
```

EDIT: PHP7, Driver version: 4

Comment: I would ask why you are using a loop like this to insert data in the first place.

Comment: @SeanLange, I accidentally fixed this by adding sleep (1); after sqlsrv_query. Do you have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: No idea why that would "fix" it. You should look at using a numbers or tally table instead of looping like this. It would be so much simpler. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this works now. No idea why.

```
$data = "a1='1', a2='2', a3='3', a4='4', a5='5', a6='6'";
    $queryInsert = 
    "   SELECT $data INTO [$tableName]
        DECLARE @i int
        SET @i=1
        WHILE (@i < $n)
        BEGIN
            INSERT [$tableName]
            SELECT $data
            SET @i = @i + 1
        END
    ";
    $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($conn1, $queryInsert);
    sleep ( 1 );
```